# What list functions are true functions in python?

Tags: python, list

By 'true function' I mean a function that cannot be recreated  with ordinary python logic. For example the append function could simply be done by creating a list one larger (through lens if you dont define that as a function) than that of the original, and then transfering the contents plus that one from a user input.

Comment: I'm sure if you're creative enough, any of the methods could be recreated via some means.

Comment: Why would you suppose such thing exists? You can implement the entire python spec in python.

Comment: I really don't understand this question. If any method is not written in Python then it is written in C. If it is written in C it could be written in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer is none. You can implement the entire specification of python, in python. It is self-hosting, as are many other languages.